# Trouble iterating through pandas column containing irregular nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nested-lists

I have annotated some data and stored each annotation as a list in a pd dataframe column df['Annotations']. However, the document may have had multiple annotations resulting in nested lists.

For example:

***[[[past, self], alcohol],[[present, self],tobacco]]***

Would be two separate annotations one for (past, self, alcohol) and another for (present, self, tobacco)

I'm having a tough time iterating through this column and updating other columns based on the values for each annotation

My dataframe is listed below:

```
       User    Annotations                           Temp   Experiencer   Tobacco   MJ    Alc.

       'xyz'    [[[past, self], alcohol],           
                 [[present, self],tobacco]]            0         0           0       0      0

       'aaa'    [[[general], marijuana]]               0         0           0       0      0 

       'bbb'    [[[past, other], alcohol], 
                 [[future, other], marijuana]]         0         0           0       0      0
```

I'd like the resulting dataframe to contain a row for each sublist(annotation). Ideally it will look like this below where in the temp column (0 = none, 1 = past, 2 = present, 3 = future) the Experiencer column (0 = general, 1 = self, 2 = other), and the remaining columns boolean (1 for present, 0 for absent):

```
       User      Temp   Experiencer   Tobacco   MJ   Alc.

       'xyz'      1          1           0      0     1

       'xyz'      2          1           1      0     0

       'aaa'      0          0           0      1     0 

       'bbb'      1          2           0      0     1 
         
       'bbb'      3          2           0      1     0
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to apply this to the column for the whole dataframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit verbose and some column names are different but it works.

```
import pandas as pd

col_map = {
    'alcohol': 'Alc',
    'tobacco': 'Tobacco',
    'marijuana': 'MJ',
    'past': 1,
    'present': 2,
    'future': 3
}
col_map2 = {'general': 0,
            'self': 1,
            'other': 2}
dfdata = {
    'user': ['xyz', 'aaa', 'bbb'],
    'anno': [
        [[['past', 'self'], 'alcohol'], [['present', 'self'], 'tobacco']],
        [[['general'], 'marijuana']],
        [[['past', 'other'], 'alcohol'],
         [['future', 'other'], 'marijuana']]
    ],
    'Temp': [0] * 3,
    'Exp': [0] * 3,
    'Tobacco': [0] * 3,
    'MJ': [0] * 3,
    'Alc': [0] * 3
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dfdata, index=range(3))
col = 'anno'
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=[x for x in df.columns if x != col])
df.set_index('user', inplace=True)
i = 0
for us in df.index:
    annos = df.loc[us, 'anno']
    for rec in annos:
        newdf.loc[i, 'user' ] = us
        newdf.loc[i, col_map[rec[-1]]] = 1
        for elem in rec[0]:
            if elem in col_map:
                newdf.loc[i, 'Temp'] = col_map[elem]
            if elem in col_map2:
                newdf.loc[i, 'Exp'] = col_map2[elem]
        i += 1

newdf.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(newdf)
```